# Opencv: VideoCapture memory leak

Tags: c++, opencv, memory-leaks, valgrind

I don't understand why I valgrind is detecting errors, since the program is literally just calling the constructor and deleting the pointer.

```
    class VideoFile
    {
    private:
        cv::VideoCapture * cap;
        unsigned int index;
    public:
        bool isValid() { return cap->isOpened(); }

        VideoFile(const std::string & path)
            :cap(new cv::VideoCapture(path))
        {
            current_index = 0;
        }

        ~VideoFile() 
        {
            delete cap;
        }
     };
```

here is the report form valgrind:
https://gist.github.com/anonymous/97d2b965d6fec43d27ac8fecb0a2026a

I am using `opencv` version  2.4.9.1

here is my main:

```
int main()
{
    std::string FilePath;
    std::cout << "Please enter the path to the video file:";
    std::cin >> FilePath;
    std::cout << std::endl;
    VideoFile videofile(FilePath);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Show your program, too...

Comment: is libgobject-2.0.so.0.4800.1 the issue?